# Xcode 6.4: External libraries not getting imported properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, cocoapods

I posted a similar question yesterday but please bear with me. I am trying to install libraries such as ObjectMapper, Alamofire, etc. using Cocoapods (updated to latest version). I can successfully install the pods but as soon as I open <>.xcworkspace, I get build errors in the library files. I had installed SwiftyJSON a month ago using CocoaPods and it didn't give me a problem at the time. I tried installing SwiftJSON in an entirely new project using CocoaPods and it is giving me the build issues now. Please help! There are no references for this!

My current Cocoapods version is 0.38.2. My project's deployment target is 8.4.

This is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'retailcatalogue' do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftyJSON'

end

target 'retailcatalogueTests' do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftyJSON'

end
```

My current version of Xcode is Version 6.4 (6E35b). Could that be a factor?

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my Xcode to 7.0.1 and everything's working great! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'retailcatalogue' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
```